# React Native FlatList horizontal paging TouchableOpacity scrollToIndex infinite loop

Tags: react-native, jsx, react-native-flatlist

I am seeing an issue with using a `TouchableOpacity` 'button' to control horizontal scrolling of a `FlatList`.  If I activate `Remote Debugging`, everything works fine, but if I turn debugging off, the touch doesn't come back and the app UI is unresponsive.

I am trying to implement a horizontally scrolling `FlatList` that is essentially a step-by-step `wizard` ui.

The `FlatList` (paging enabled, horizontal) has 3 to 7 items in the data array and I have `prev` and `next` buttons implemented with `TouchableOpacity` components in a separate view at the bottom of the screen.
I have a custom View component that will represent the contents of each step (for now, it has a single Text label).

Tapping next or prev should scroll to the next index in the FlatList.
Using something like:

```jsx
this.flatListRef.scrollToIndex({index: this.state.currentStepIndex + 1, animated: true});
```

I created an Issue in the React Native GitHub repo.  Has anyone seen this behavior?  Any known work arounds?

I see this on Android and iOS.
Here's my environment:

```jsx
react: ^16.3.2 => 16.3.2
react-native: ^0.55.3 => 0.55.3
```

Here's my original code:

```jsx
  render() {
    console.log('Render newrequestscreen', this.state, this.flatListRef)
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={baseStyles.safeAreaDark}>
        <View style={baseStyles.swipeContainerView} >
          <Text style ={baseStyles.emptyListSubtitleText} > {this.state.flexItems.length == this.state.currentStepIndex ? 'Review & Submit' : 'Step ' + (this.state.currentStepIndex + 1) + ' of ' + (this.state.flexItems.length) }</Text>
        </View>
        <FlatList
          ref={(ref) => { this.flatListRef = ref; }}
          scrollEnabled={false}
          initialNumToRender={1}
          initialScrollIndex={0}
          refreshing={false}
          pagingEnabled={true}
          horizontal
          getItemLayout={(data, index) => (
            {length: Dimensions.get('window').width, offset: Dimensions.get('window').width * index, index}
          )}
          data={this.state.flexItems}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = { false }
          decelerationRate={0}
          renderItem={({item, index}) => {
            return (
              <View style={baseStyles.swipeContainerView} pointerEvents='none' >
                <Text style ={baseStyles.emptyListSubtitleText} >{item.promptText}</Text>
              </View>
              )
            }
          }
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.type}/>
        <View style={baseStyles.swipeContainerView} >
          <View style={baseStyles.requestNavView}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={this._previousStep.bind(this)}
              style={requestComponentStyles.locationCaptureButton}>
              <Text style={requestComponentStyles.locationCaptureButtonText}>Prev Step</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={this._nextStep.bind(this)}
              style={requestComponentStyles.locationCaptureButton}>
              <Text style={requestComponentStyles.locationCaptureButtonText}>Next Step</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }

  _nextStep() {
    console.log('next tapped...', this.flatListRef)
    if (this.state.currentStepIndex < this.state.flexItems.length - 1) {
      this.flatListRef.scrollToIndex({index: this.state.currentStepIndex + 1, animated: true});
      this.setState(function(prevState, props) {
        return {
          currentStepIndex: prevState.currentStepIndex + 1
        };
      });
    }
  }

  _previousStep() {
    console.log('prev tapped...', this.flatListRef)
    if (this.state.currentStepIndex > 0) {
      this.flatListRef.scrollToIndex({index: this.state.currentStepIndex - 1, animated: true});
      this.setState(function(prevState, props) {
        return {
          currentStepIndex: prevState.currentStepIndex - 1
        };
      });
    }
  }
```

Here's a screen shot of what I'm building (the gray area with the text 'location' is a full-width item in the horizontal `FlatList`):

[My image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxRIl.png)

I appreciate any help or thoughts on this!  Thanks!!

Update/Note: If I remove the FlatList the TouchableOpacity buttons work fine, so there definitely seems to be some sort of incompatibility between the FlatList and other Touchable elements on the same screen.

Edited the above code to provide a very 'bare-bones' example of this issue.  If I run using the debugger, all is well, but if I don't, the tap on Prev or Next `TouchableOpacity` buttons never returns and the UI hangs.

Update: If I change things so that my FlatList's data and currentList props are not part of this.state, I can advance the scroll index via the TouchableOpacity press. The problem is, I would like to update the state so that a progress view shows the current step information (e.g. 'Step x of y').

Updating the state in the _nextStep() or _previousStep() functions shouldn't cause an infinite loop condition, right? I thought the FlatList would only re-render when the data or extraData props changed. Like I said earlier, if I run in the debugger, I don't go into an infinite loop.

This version seems to work - I also did a clean, build in Xcode:

```jsx
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      stepIndex: 0
    }

    this.currentStepIndex = 0;

    this.nextStep = this._nextStep.bind(this);
    this.previousStep = this._previousStep.bind(this);

    this.flexItems =  [
      { promptText: 'step 1', type: 'intro' },
      { promptText: 'step 2', type: 'location' },
      { promptText: 'step 3', type: 'pickList' },
      { promptText: 'step 4', type: 'longText' },
      { promptText: 'step 5', type: 'photo' },
      { promptText: 'Review and Submit', type: 'review' }
    ];

    this.nextStep = this._nextStep.bind(this);
    this.previousStep = this._previousStep.bind(this);

    console.log('State: ', this.state);
  }

  render() {
    console.log('Render new request screen')
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={baseStyles.safeAreaDark}>
        <View style={baseStyles.newRequestContainerView} >
        <View style={baseStyles.requestProgressView} >
          <Text style ={baseStyles.emptyListSubtitleText} > {this.flexItems.length == this.state.stepIndex ? 'Review & Submit' : 'Step ' + (this.state.stepIndex + 1) + ' of ' + (this.flexItems.length) }</Text>
        </View>
        <FlatList
          ref={(ref) => { this.flatListRef = ref; }}
          scrollEnabled={false}
          initialNumToRender={1}
          initialScrollIndex={0}
          refreshing={false}
          pagingEnabled={true}
          horizontal
          getItemLayout={(data, index) => (
            {length: Dimensions.get('window').width, offset: Dimensions.get('window').width * index, index}
          )}
          data={this.flexItems}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = { false }
          decelerationRate={0}
          renderItem={({item, index}) => {
            if (item.type === 'intro') {
              return (
                <View style={baseStyles.swipeContainerView} >
                  <View style={baseStyles.swipeContentView} >
                    <Text style ={baseStyles.emptyListSubtitleText}>All About Potholes</Text>
                  </View>
                </View>
              )

            } else if (item.type === 'pickList') {
              return (
                <View style={baseStyles.swipeContainerView} >
                  <View style={baseStyles.swipeContentView} >
                    <Text style ={baseStyles.emptyListSubtitleText} >{item.promptText}</Text>
                  </View>
                </View>
              )
            } else  {
              return (
                <View style={baseStyles.swipeContainerView} >
                  <View style={baseStyles.swipeContentView} >
                    <Text style ={baseStyles.emptyListSubtitleText} >{item.promptText}</Text>
                  </View>
                </View>
              )
            }
          }}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.type}/>
      </View>
      <View style={baseStyles.requestNavView}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={this.previousStep}
          style={requestComponentStyles.locationCaptureButton}>
          <Text style={requestComponentStyles.locationCaptureButtonText}>Prev Step</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={this.nextStep}
          style={requestComponentStyles.locationCaptureButton}>
          <Text style={requestComponentStyles.locationCaptureButtonText}> {this.state.stepIndex < this.flexItems.length - 1 ? 'Next Step' : 'Submit'}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

    </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }

  _nextStep() {
    console.log('next tapped...')

    if (this.currentStepIndex < this.flexItems.length - 1) {
      this.currentStepIndex = this.currentStepIndex + 1;
      this.flatListRef.scrollToIndex({index: this.currentStepIndex, animated: true});

      this.setState (
        {
          stepIndex: this.currentStepIndex
        }
      )

    } else {
      this._onDismissScreen();
    }
  }

  _previousStep () {
    console.log('prev tapped...')
    if (this.currentStepIndex > 0) {
      this.currentStepIndex = this.currentStepIndex - 1;
      this.flatListRef.scrollToIndex({index: this.currentStepIndex, animated: true});
      this.setState (
        {
          stepIndex: this.currentStepIndex
        }
      )
    }
  }
```